# Cakephp: create new object and access controller class in index.php root page that is inside webroot folder

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to access CustomersController class from index.php page that is inside webroot folder in cakephp 3.When I use below code, it says it cannot find the class.

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/src/Controller/CustomersController.php';
$customers = new CustomersController;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the error I get from cakephp index.php page: "Error: Class 'CustomersController' not found "

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: Also you are writing ``ServersController`` and you want to load a ``CustomersController``

Comment: sorry for confusion. I just updated my question.

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" Yes, **this makes absolutely no sense at all.** Why do you want to do that? You try to instantiate a controller outside of the context of the framework. I recommend you to start over by reading http://book.cakephp.org and doing the tutorial. What you try to do is totally wrong.

Comment: I understand that I can create routing and point / (root) path to any index page like / -> /customers/ and make it a home path to the application if I want to access views. What I dont understand is why there is webroot folder and if it cannot access classes from controllers then what is the purpose of having it? Is that just there because CakePHP wanted to display the initial configuration of cakephp?

Comment: `webroot/index.php` is a file which normally (read: always) you don't modify. If you're doing what's in the question, you've either misunderstood how to use CakePHP (please see the docs, [here's a good place to start](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html)) or don't really want to use CakePHP/a framework.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that CakePHP 3 uses [PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading (check also [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)) and also [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php). If you go and remove the namespace from from the controller you will see that it works. But this will probably break other stuff.